# Recording military vehicles

Tags: field, recording, military

Has anyone ever done any recording of military vehicles (i.e. tanks, utility vehicles)?

I'm wondering what to expect in terms of costs. I've done car recordings before so I'm familiar with equipment and track rentals and all that but I'm assuming things like driver fees and vehicle rentals don't really apply when you're dealing with the military. Or do they?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Depends on whether you deal with the actual military or private collectors. If military, then you should expect to go through several stages of clearance and permissions, as well as heavy security and (probably) limited access. You won't be faced with driver fees or vehicle rentals. If private collectors, you'll most likely need to travel to where they are and record wherever they are able to operate their equipment. And rather than pay fees and rentals, instead you'll negotiate a flat-fee, hourly rate or reimbursement for fuel / ammo.